# How to fill image to whole space in ion-img without losing aspect ratio?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

My current progress stuck at something like this. I need help

[image]

I need the picture in the ion-img to fill its container without losing its aspect.
here is my html code

```
<ion-col class='left-content'>
  <ion-img [src]='voucher.image'></ion-img>
</ion-col>
```

here is my scss code

```
ion-img {
  min-width: 5.7em;
  min-height: 5.7em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  @include my-img-shadow();
}

.left-content {
  padding-top: 0.8em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `object-fit:cover`.

```
ion-img {
    ...
    object-fit:cover;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.ion-img { 
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
  object-fit:cover; 
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.